# DB Migrate not reflected on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, database-migration

I recently created a db migration which works fine locally. I pushed to heroku and ran

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Whilst the command doesn't seem to throw an error, I can see the database hasn't been updated with the column I've tried to add to a table. I've tried running `heroku rake db:setup` but to no avail. Additionally, I've also tried restarting heroku after both commands but it still doesn't work.

Anybody have this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to be specific with `heroku rake db:migrate:up VERSION=xxx`
I had similar problems and what I did was to reset the database, if that doesn't work, I would migrate down all migrations (one by one) and add them up again, of course only if you can afford to loose all your data, alternatively download the database and investigate. The problems I had with recreating the db were related to the fact that I was changing the migrations and that in heroku I had a shared database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - exactly how did you reset the db? heroku doesn't support db reset...

Comment: uhmmmm.... maybe that's only what I tried to do and then I ended up migrating down and up again

Comment: Yep going up and down the migrations did it - strange! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Next time you can also check `rake db:version` to be the same as your local one, if it's not you can run an empty migration up/down to synch it, not very nice, but works